# How to create a Rich Edit programmatically in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, richedit

After the previous question with issue in inserting a Rich Edit control to MFC Dialog based application I am here with another question:

I am using Visual Studio 2015 So I am creating a Dialog based MFC application:

If I add a Rich Edit control from the Toolbox it works fine But: How to create it programmatically?

In `InitInstance` I added:

```
AfxInitRichEdit2();
```

And in button "Press" handler l added:

```
CRichEditCtrl edt;
RECT rct{ 10, 10, 200, 200 };
edt.Create(WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE, rct, this, 150);
```

But when running the application No Rich edit there?!!

Comment: Well, did you press the button to create the RichEdit?  Also, when `edt` goes out of scope, it will destroy the RichEdit, so you should make that variable be a member of your dialog class instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes for sure. How should I do it?

Comment: Move the declaration of `edt` into the declaration of your dialog class (what `this` refers to), in its `public`, `protected`, or `private` section, your choice. Do you not know how to work with classes in general?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Oh thank you!!! I changed it to dynamic and it works. `CrichEditCtrl* edt = new CRichEditCtr...`. Now I should make it a global scope for example.

Comment: Well, now you have a memory leak, because now you need to call `delete edt;` when you are done using the RichEdit, but you can't do that because `edt` is a local variable and you lose access to it.  Again, you need to make `edt` be a member of your dialog class instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It works thank you. the problem really it is on the stack and it gets out of scope thus its ctor is called. as a result no edit there.

Comment: That is only a problem when `edt` is a local variable of the procedure that declares it, not when it is a member of your dialog class

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I got what you really wanted to say. I know there's a memory leak. Ok I declare it as a member variable. So this issue concern each type of control? doesn't it? Remy is it good to create it on the stack or dynamically allocated?

Comment: If you allocate it dynamically, you have to keep track of it so you can destroy it later when you are done using it. If it is a member of the dialog class, there is no need to allocate it dynamically, it will go out of scope when the dialog object is destroyed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'll always appreciate you. You are always helpful and informative.

Comment: @RemyLebeau One last question: If i created the control with Wizard does it mean that the wizard created it as a member variable?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: After declaring the control as a member variable of the dialog: if i press  the button "PRESS" I get the dialog there and everything is ok. But if re-press the button I get assertion dialog. I figured out by : `if(!m_richEdit) m_richEdit.Create(...)` so it is created once. Does this correct?

Comment: Yes, the wizard creates controls as members.  And yes, you would have to check that the RichEdit window hasn't already been created before creating a new one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks again for the thorough, useful explanation.